# Unable to set border to ratingbar for marshallow version

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have Ratingbar for which I have set border color.It works great in other version of mobile.But, in marshamallow unable to set color to the border of ratingbar.

Comment: Used this code                                                                          RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.rating);                     Drawable drawable = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable(); drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"),PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);